# Unzip The Zip Archive With PHP

Tags: php, zip

I Have A Problem About extract the zip file with PHP 
I try many shared script on the web 
but it still doesn't work 
 
the last script i try is this script :

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('data.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/extract/');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'woot!';
} else {
  echo 'doh!';
}
?>
```

I am always get the else condition when the script is run , 
I've tried replacing the `data.zip` and the `/extract/` path to complete path `http://localhost/basedata/data.zip` and `http://localhost/basedata/extract/` but I still got the else condition , Anyone can help me?

Here Is My whole script and the zip file
http://www.mediafire.com/?c49c3xdxjlm58ey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check which error code gives open (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php), that will give you some help.

Error codes are this:

```
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_EXISTS -10
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INCONS - 21
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INVAL - 18
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_MEMORY - 14
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOENT - 9
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOZIP - 19
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OPEN - 11
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_READ - 5
    ZIPARCHIVE::ER_SEEK - 4
```

Comment: I've got the error number 19
it's mean its not zip archive 
but no, the file is zip archive and placed on the same directory with the script

Comment: What is your php version ? have you tried with another zip files ? there is some php version with a bug that you can't open zip files with more size than 1.5 gb ~ https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55383

Comment: Problem solved , previously I create the zip file with fwrite command , but when i try to create manually the zip file with winrar , its work , the problem is the zip file i created from fwrite command is not actually a zip file  

thanks for the advice to check the error code

Answer (score 0):

ZipArchive uses file paths, not URLs.

For example, if your web server's document root is `/srv/www`, specify `/srv/www/basedata/data.zip` (or wherever the file is on the server's local file system), *not* `http://localhost/basedata/data.zip`.

If the .ZIP file is on a remote computer, change the script to download it first before extracting it, though this does not seem to be your case.

Furthermore, the user the PHP script *runs as* needs to have read permission for the Zip file and write permission for the destination for extracted files.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring your `$zip` (ziparchive) incorrectly

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
```

is missing parentheses

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('data.zip')) {
```

Comment: `new ZipArchive` is same as `new ZipArchive()`