# ZipArchive not opening file - Error Code: 19

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Im having issues with my code being able to open a zip file that i have uploaded and moved into a folder, the zip file uploads fine and you can open it in any Zip program however, when i attempt to open it with ZipArchive to extract the data it errors.

```
    $path = "../"; // Upload directory      
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . $name))
             $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
    }

    $kioskFile = $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
    $kioskFile = explode(".", $kioskFile);
    $kioskFile = $kioskFile[0];
    $zipFile = "../" . $kioskFile . ".zip";     

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($zipFile);
    if ($res === true) {
        $zip->extractTo("./");
        $zip->close();
    } else {
        echo "Error Cannot Open Zip File - Error Code: ";
    }
```

When i run the code it shows me a Error Code 19

ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOZIP - 19

This is the error im getting, however the file exists and if i use zip_open, it returns that it can open the zip file.

Any help would be very greatful

**EDIT1** 
If i upload a zip file that i manually create (using a zip program) then the upload works fine. However if i use a ZipArchive created zip file, then it instantly errors with a error 19.

**EDIT2** 
I have now added a check to make sure the file exists in the right directory and also put a print of the location also, both match, however still the same issue. Error 19

```
    $path = "../"; // Upload directory      
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . $name))
             $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
    }

    $kioskFile = $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
    $kioskFile = explode(".", $kioskFile);
    $kioskFile = $kioskFile[0];
    $realpath = realpath("../");
    $zipFile = $realpath . "\\" .  $kioskFile . ".zip";     

    if (file_exists($zipFile)) {
        $extract = zip_extract($zipFile, "../");
        if ($extract === TRUE) {

        } else {
            echo "The file " . $zipFile . " cannot be opened";  
        }
    } else {
        echo "The file " . $zipFile . " does not exist";
        die();
    }
```

**UPDATE1**
So i think ive narrowed it down to either this bit of code, or the download script that i use to download the .zip file from the system, if i leave the zip on the system and use the exact same bit of code it works fine.

Here is my download code, maybe ive missed something on this that is causing the issue.

```
    $fileID = $_GET['id'];
    $backupLoc = "backups/";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM backups WHERE id = '" . addslashes($fileID) .  "' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res); 
    $backupFile = $row['backupFile'];
    $zipFile = $backupLoc . "/" . $backupFile . ".zip";
    $zipSize = filesize($zipFile);

    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($zipFile). '"'); 
    ob_end_flush();
    readfile($zipFile);
    exit;
    die();
```

Comment: Have you done a var dump for path and file name?

Comment: Yup file name is 100% correct, i can even put it into my zip program (the url that is given from php) and it will go and open it in the zip program so the location of the zip and its filename are correct

Comment: maybe this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142093/unzip-the-zip-archive-with-php

Comment: I already researched that URL before posting, and the Poster of that had used fwrite to make his Zip File, this is a zip file that was created using ZipArchive in the first place

Comment: have you tried open other zip created from other systems?

Comment: If i use a zip that wasnt created by ZipArchive then it will read and extract... it only seems to be zip files that ZipArchive has made.

Comment: it seems to me a creating bug then =) sorry that i cannot help you more than this =/

Comment: I have updated to include a test to make sure that the file exists and also my download.php script that i use to download the .zip, i think thats narrowed down where the issue might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was the download.php file that was causing the issue, here is the solution. which was to do a OB CLEAN rather than a Flush

```
    ///echo "<div style='padding: 50px;'>Please Wait .....</div>";
    $fileID = $_GET['id'];
    $backupLoc = "backups/";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM backups WHERE id = '" . addslashes($fileID) .  "' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res); 
    $backupFile = $row['backupFile'];
    $zipFile = $backupLoc . "/" . $backupFile . ".zip";
    $zipSize = filesize($zipFile);

    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($zipFile). '"'); 
    //ob_end_flush();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    readfile($zipFile);
    exit;
    die();
```

Answer (score 4):

Open the archive with a text or hex editor and make sure you have the 'PK' signature at the start of the file.
If you have any HTML before that signature, it would suggest that your buffers are not being cleaned or are being flushed when they should not be, meaning that PHP ZipArchive will assume an invalid archive.

Comment: to add to the answer, you can clean buffer using ob_clean()

Comment: After hours and hours the `ob_clean()` was the solution

Comment: Reading the zip file is smart. I did this, and realized that I was receiving an XML file, not a zip file, from the API I was calling. It described the error, due to my API syntax being wrong. Reading ftw!