# Zip archive is not extract the file showing 19 error message

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

```
    $json_path = BUILDERUX_JSON_UPLOAD . $json_folder . '/';


$zip = new ZipArchive;

$res = $zip->open(BUILDERUX_JSON_UPLOAD.$filename);

if ($res === TRUE)
    {
        echo "working1";
    $zip->extractTo($json_path);
    $zip->close();
}
```

path is correct but file is not extract and getting 19 error message .

Im having issues with my code being able to open a zip file that i have uploaded and moved into a folder, the zip file uploads fine and you can open it in any Zip program however, when i attempt to open it with ZipArchive to extract the data it errors.

When i run the code it shows me a Error Code 19

Comment: Please anybody know the issue then please let me know so i can check it

Comment: Did you try the link below? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503569/ziparchive-not-opening-file-error-code-19

Comment: yes but not working ..:(

Comment: Any body know about the issue. I need asap.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php#108601) and this entry, error code 19 could be that the file is not a zip archive.